# Reference request - Any suggestion for good Abstract Algebra pdf for computer science?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, computer-science

I'm a computer science student and I'm starting to learn Abstract Algebra next week.

I'd like to get a suggestions for good PDF book about Abstract Algebra.

Thanks!

Comment: It would be a good idea if you tell us about your background, that way people will have a better idea of what to recommend.

Comment: I am not sure about a free pdf, but you can find this book for US $6 and it is a wonderful and as applied as you'll find "A Book of Abstract Algebra: Second Edition (Dover Books on Mathematics) by Charles C Pinter.

Comment: @AdriánBarquero Amm .. I've just end up with Linear Algebra course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good textbook: [Abstract Algebra: Theory and Applications](http://abstract.ups.edu/) by Tom Judson. I learned abstract algebra from it and it has a lot of computer programming exercises as well as a SAGE companion. Its introductory but goes through a lot of important results in introductory abstract algebra. Moreover its free!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions:

- http://www.math.miami.edu/~ec/book/
- http://shoup.net/ntb/
- http://abstract.ups.edu/ (go to download section)
- http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/ (go to Abstract Algebra: The Basic Graduate Year)
- http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/gbooks/geomath.html (click on math-basics.pdf)

There are some variations in the listed books so take a look at the table of contents at least to get an idea of which one will suit your needs.

Comment: I just saw Robert's answer and his suggested book is coincidentally the third one in my list. Seems like a good abstract algebra book for students in computer science from his comments.